# Sockets - Jogo da Velha / Jogo do Galo MULTIPLAYER

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, jogos, redes

**POST EDITADO**

Estou a criar o chamado 'Jogo da velha' (ou 'Jogo do Galo'), neste momento estou a tentar criar uma funcionalidade que permita que dois jogadores em dispositivos diferentes - embora na mesma rede - possam jogar um contra o outro.

Este é um excerto do código do servidor no qual estou a tentar fazer com que a função **game()** - que engloba o jogo todo (inputs para os nicknames, quadro, possibilidades de ganhar, etc...), ***mas na parte do encode o suposto é fazer com que esta função execute no programa do client, e neste caso ele é executado no programa do servidor)!***

Any help?

```
def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))

    mySocket.listen(1)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if not data:
                    break
            print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))

            data = game
            print ("sending: ")
            conn.send(data().encode())

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Que eu saiba, TicTacToe é o jogo da velha. Não conhecia o termo "jogo do galo".

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sou de Portugal e não do Brasil, também desconhecia o termo "jogo da velha", abraço!

Comment: Oi Swabadzu. Realmente, a sua pergunta está ampla, porque você não tem exatamente uma dúvida/dificuldade a respeito do uso de comunicação em redes. Eu sugiro que você tente primeiramente fazer algum tutorial de uso de sockets bem básico (para comunicar texto mesmo entre um ponto e outro). Esse, por exemplo: http://wiki.python.org.br/SocketBasico Então, você pode pensar a respeito de como implementar o que você precisa.

Comment: A comunicação será essencialmente a mesma, mas cabe a você implementar a interface de comandos remota. Isto é, você precisará ser capaz de enviar e receber algum identificador que contenha a "jogada" (em qual posição o jogador agiu). Há várias formas de pensar sobre isso (não é possível "associar" a função `playerX` a uma comunicação; você precisa executá-la no lado do cliente/jogador, e então enviar a "instrução" com a ação para o lado do servidor). Mas garanta antes que você já sabe fazer a comunicação (por isso sugeri o tutorial).

Comment: @LuizVieira Muito obrigado, that was really helpful!

Comment: Código alterado, pergunta mais específica!

Comment: Continua confuso. O que é `game`? Seria uma função? Se sim, quando você faz `conn.send(data().encode())`, o Python primeiro executa a função `data()` (que é igual a executar `game()`), depois codifica o que essa função retorna (`data().encode()`) e então envia esse resultado codificado pela conexão (`conn.send(data().encode())`). Se você quer enviar o "objeto" (?) `data`, você deveria fazer `conn.send(data.encode())`. Mas isso vai depender de o seu objeto ser passível de codificação (isto é, ter um método `encode`).

Comment: @LuizVieira game() é uma função que engloba todo o jogo (inputs, o quadro do jogo, as possibilidades de vencer, basicamente tudo) e eu estou a tentar passar isso para o cliente, mas não está a dar

Comment: Mas por que você quer passar tudo isso para o cliente? O ideal é o cliente já ter esse código, e o servidor somente passar pra ele o *estado* atual do jogo.

Comment: Você fez um programa mais simples que comunica **texto** entre o servidor e o cliente? Já entendeu essa parte? Se sim, eu sugiro a seguinte abordagem: edite novamente a questão e poste o código que você já tentou (para demonstrar que vc ao menos entendeu como é a comunicação em rede). Então, pergunte como que se faz para transmitir informação de estado (de um jogo) usando esse mesmo mecanismo. Dai eu voto para reabrir a questão, e se possível até tento dar uma resposta.

Comment: @LuizVieira O excerto do código que eu coloquei transmite texto entre o servidor e o cliente trocando a definição da variável data de "game" para uma string. Eu testei e funciona, a única coisa que eu mudei foi passar de texto para a função completa em si ( game() )!

Comment: Ok. Vou votar para reabrir. Se reabrirem, eu tento responder.

Comment: @LuizVieira Penso que já esteja reaberto!

Comment: Ah, ok. Vou tentar preparar uma resposta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo exemplo que de código que você forneceu, você parece ter entendido que a comunicação via socket te permite enviar e receber mensagens. Ok. Mas você insiste em tentar executar uma função remotamente (ou associar uma função a um cliente TCP/IP), e isso *não é tão trivial*. Sockets podem ser usados para fazer isso? Claro que sim, mas você vai precisar implementar um recurso de "chamada remota" manualmente. Se essa for mesma a sua intenção, procure por bibliotecas que já fazem esse tipo de coisa (RPC, de *Remote Procedure Call*, ou Chamada Remota de Procedimento), pois reinventar a roda é bobagem. Alguns exemplos podem ser encontrados [neste link do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python).

Por outro lado, jogos não costumam fazer chamada remota de procedimentos. Eles costumam comunicar entre o servidor e o(s) jogador(es) o *estado do jogo*. Então o seu problema é, na verdade, como representar o estado do jogo de forma que ele possa ser transmitido via sockets.

O mais comum é [serializar/deserializar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) um objeto que representa o estado do jogo, e usar os bytes que representam esse estado na comunicação. O Python tem um monte de opções para serialização, basta dar uma olhada por aí ([sugestão de link](https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/serializacao-de-objetos-em-python/)). Mas, no seu caso, como é algo trivial, a minha sugestão é converter a matriz de peças do tabuleiro em uma string. Fácil, rápido e inspecionável! (basta imprimir o resultado de `save`, por exemplo).

Assim, fiz uma classe de exemplo que representa o tabuleiro do jogo:

```
import numpy as np
from random import *

class GameState:
    """
    Classe que representa o estado do jogo.
    """

    # -------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Construtor. Initializa o tabuleiro 3x3 vazio.
        """
        self.board = [[''] * 3 for n in range(3)]

    # -------------------------------------------------
    def save(self):
        """
        Salva os dados do tabuleiro para uma string.

        Gera uma string com as peças do tabuleiro separadas por
        ponto-e-vírgula (';'), de forma que o estado do jogo possa
        ser comunicado via socket.

        Retorno
        ----------
        data: str
            String de texto com os dados do tabuleiro separados por
            ponto-e-vírgula (';'), prontos para serem comunicados.     
        """
        return ';'.join([';'.join(x) for x in self.board])

    # -------------------------------------------------
    def restore(self, data):
        """
        Restaura os dados do tabuleiro a partir de uma string.

        Lê uma string com as peças do tabuleiro separadas por
        ponto-e-vírgula (';'), de forma que o estado do jogo possa ser
        comunicado via socket.

        Parâmetros
        ----------
        data: str
            String de texto com os dados do tabuleiro separados por um
            ponto-e-vírgula (';'), prontos para serem atualizados neste
            objeto.
        """
        self.board = np.reshape(data.split(';'), (3,3)).tolist()

    # -------------------------------------------------
    def print(self):
        """
        Imprime o tabuleiro em um formato visual.
        """
        print("+---+---+---+")
        for row in self.board:
            print('|{}|{}|{}|'.format(row[0].center(3, ' '), row[1].center(3, ' '), row[2].center(3, ' ')))
            print("+---+---+---+")

    # -------------------------------------------------
    def move(self, row, col, piece):
        """
        Faz uma jogada no tabuleiro, nas posições dadas.

        Parâmetros
        ----------
        row: int
            Número da linha no tabuleiro, no intervalo [0,2].
        col: int
            Número da coluna no tabuleiro, no intervalo [0,2].
        piece: str
            Letra com o símbolo jogado, entre as opções 'o' e 'x'.        
        """

        # Valida os parâmetros de entrada
        if row < 0 or row > 2:
            raise RuntimeError('Número de linha inválido: {}'.format(row))
        if col < 0 or col > 2:
            raise RuntimeError('Número de coluna inválido: {}'.format(col))
        piece = piece.lower()
        if piece != 'x' and piece != 'o':
            raise RuntimeError('Peça inválida: {}'.format(piece))

        # Verifica se a posição jogada está vazia
        if self.board[row][col] != '':
            raise RuntimeError('Posição do tabuleiro já preenchida: {}x{}'.format(row, col))

        # Faz a jogada
        self.board[row][col] = piece

    # -------------------------------------------------
    def moveRandom(self, piece):
        """
        Faz uma jogada aleatória no tabuleiro, em uma das posições vazias.

        Parâmetros
        ----------
        piece: str
            Letra com o símbolo jogado, entre as opções 'o' e 'x'.
        """

        # Cria uma lista com as posições vazias
        options = []
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if self.board[row][col] == '':
                    options.append((row, col))

        # Faz uma permutação aleatória nessa lista
        shuffle(options)

        # Faz a jogada na primeira posição da lista
        if len(options) > 0:
            row = options[0][0]
            col = options[0][1]
            self.move(row, col, piece)
```

O código está documentado, mas o pulo do gato está nos métodos `save` e `restore` que respectivamente geram uma string para você enviar via socket e restaura o tabuleiro a partir de uma string recebida via socket. Logo, você pode usar isso para "montar" o seu jogo mais ou menos dessa forma:

Servidor:

```
import socket
from gamestate import GameState

# Cria o socket TCP/IP
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Faz o bind no endereco e porta
server_address = ('localhost', 5000)
sock.bind(server_address)

# Fica ouvindo por conexoes
sock.listen(1)

while True:

    print('Aguardando a conexao do jogador')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print('Jogador chegou! :)')

        # Cria um tabuleiro de jogo vazio
        board = GameState()

        # Faz uma jogada aleatoria
        board.moveRandom('o')
        print('Eu joguei:')
        board.print()

        # Envia o tabuleiro para o jogador
        connection.sendall(board.save().encode('utf-8'))

        # Processa em loop
        while True:
            # Recebe a jogada do jogador
            data = connection.recv(1024)

            # Checa se a conexao do jogador foi terminada
            if not data:
                print('Jogador se foi. :(')
                break

            # Converte para string e restaura no tabuleiro
            board.restore(data.decode('utf-8'))

            print('O jogador jogou:')
            board.print()

            # Faz outra jogada aleatoria
            board.moveRandom('o')
            print('Eu joguei:')
            board.print()

            # Envia o tabuleiro para o jogador
            connection.sendall(board.save().encode('utf-8'))

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

Cliente:

```
import socket
import sys
from gamestate import GameState

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 5000)
print('Conectando ao servidor {} na porta {}'.format(server_address[0], server_address[1]))
sock.connect(server_address)

# Cria um tabuleiro de jogo vazio
board = GameState()

try:

    while True:

        # Recebe a jogada do servidor
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        board.restore(data.decode('utf-8'))

        print('O servidor jogou:')
        board.print()

        print('Faça a sua jogada:')
        print('------------------')

        nok = True
        while nok:
            row = int(input('Digite a linha:'))
            col = int(input('Digite a coluna:'))

            nok = False
            try:
                board.move(row, col, 'x')
            except:
                nok = True
                print('Linha ou coluna inválida. Tente novamente.')

        # Envia o tabuleiro para o servidor
        sock.sendall(board.save().encode('utf-8'))

finally:
    print('Encerrando o cliente')
    sock.close()
```

Resultado de uma sessão de teste:

```
No servidor:
-----------------------------

Aguardando a conexao do jogador
Jogador chegou! :)
Eu joguei:
+---+---+---+
| o |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
O jogador jogou:
+---+---+---+
| o |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   | x |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
Eu joguei:
+---+---+---+
| o | o |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   | x |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+

No cliente:
------------------
Conectando ao servidor localhost na porta 5000
O servidor jogou:
+---+---+---+
| o |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
Faça a sua jogada:
------------------
Digite a linha:1
Digite a coluna:2
O servidor jogou:
+---+---+---+
| o | o |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   | x |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
Faça a sua jogada:
------------------
Digite a linha:
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, sem dúvida que está muito mais elaborada do que estava à espera, muito obrigado!